# Python 2.3 code compilation in Linux

Tags: python, linux, command-line, python-2.x

I am facing issues while compiling the code (.pyc) in python 2.3. The same code I can compile in 2.6 successfully using below command.

```
python -m py_compile <<script name>>
```

So need a help to compile the code (.pyc) in 2.3.

Comment: I cannot find any evidence that the `python -m` switch wouldn't work on Python 2.3, or that the module isn't available. What problems or error messages did you encounter?

Comment: What kind of issues? Are you using features, that aren't available in 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

The [`pycompile` module](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/module-pycompile.html) was already part of the standard library in Python 2.3 (it has been since Python 1.5). You can either run it directly or open the interpreter, import it and use it that way.

If you don't know where the module is located, use:

```
python -c 'import pycompile; print pycompile.__file__'
```

then use:

```
python /full/path/to/pycompile.py <<script_name>>
```

There is also a [`compileall` module / script](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/module-compileall.html) that can bytecompile whole directories, recursively.

I'm almost certain however, that using `python -m` already worked in Python 2.3, so the original command line *should* just work:

```
python2.3 -m pycompile <<script_name>>
```